# Send email of bitmap android STUCK

Tags: java, android, email, bitmap

I have managed my way around getting a screenshot and creating the bitmap file.
Now I am trying to send this to a specific gmail (mine). I dont get any errors while running but also no email.
What am I doing wrong? I am sure its something stupid but cant figure it out.
Here is my Main Activity.

```
   package com.example.publi.myapplication1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;
    Bitmap mbitmap;
    Button captureScreenShot;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("Thank you for Ordering ALMA");

        captureScreenShot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capture_screen_shot);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    }

    public void screenShot(View view) {
        mbitmap = getBitmapOFRootView(captureScreenShot);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(mbitmap);
        createImage(mbitmap);
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapOFRootView(View v) {
        View rootview = v.getRootView();
        rootview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap1 = rootview.getDrawingCache();
        return bitmap1;
    }

    public void createImage(Bitmap bmp) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                "/capturedscreenandroid.jpg");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            outputStream.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void sendMail(String path) {
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[]{"my@gmail.com"});
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                "Alma Test Mail");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                "This is an autogenerated mail from Alma's InAppMail app");
        emailIntent.setType("image/png");
        Uri myUri = Uri.parse("file://" + path);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, myUri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
    }
}
```

I also added mail.jar, activation.jar, aditional.jar
Together with below in manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Where do you call your methods? Does your email app get open?

Comment: Why do you set the MIME type to a PNG, if the image is a JPG? As in `bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                "/capturedscreenandroid.jpg");` but then `emailIntent.setType("image/png");`

Comment: @Perak My app open yes and it works ie create the screenshot. but does not send email.

Comment: He did not ask if your app opens. He wanted to know if the GMail app opens. Or another email client. Or the 'which email client dialog'?

Comment: @Hrundi good point.  oversite. but still dont send email.

Comment: As @PrerakSola points out, the button doesn't seem to have any callback (onClickListener). Did you define one ? In the layout xml maybe ?

Comment: Facepalm true Will  add call back and revert back

Comment: @brainsandwich good gatch. But it can't be defined in the xml, because the method signature for the xml `onclick()` listener requires a parameter of tipe View. I.e.: `public void sendMail(view View) {`

Comment: Good to know ! Never tried setting callbacks over there though

Comment: I only have one button that takes the screenshot. I need to add the callback to the same button. any suggestions creating it as onClickListener or in xml?